# ServiceStack Response Default Values

Tags: c#, servicestack

`[Default]` data annotation works with ORMLite. However, it won't work with default values of a response. Is there anything similar to the `[Default]` attribute that is for response DTO?

Considering the following code:

```
[Route("api/hello")]
public class Hello {
    public string Ping { get; set; }
}
public class HelloResponse {
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    [Default(typeof(string), "(nothing comes back!)")]
    public string Pong { get; set; }
}
```

I want Response DTO Pong property to have a default value "(nothing comes back!)" instead of just null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set it in the constructor. DTOs in ServiceStack are plain C# objects. Nothing special.

```
public class HelloResponse 
{
    public HelloResponse() 
    {
        this.Pong = "(nothing comes back!)";
    }

    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    public string Pong { get; set; }
}
```

The constructor for a class will always run before any properties set in an object initializer:

```
var resp = new HelloResponse();
Console.WriteLine(resp.Pong); // "(nothing comes back!)"

resp = new HelloResponse 
{
    Pong = "Foobar";
};
Console.WriteLine(resp.Pong); // "Foobar"
```